Justification for the Moral Ought
For this question, I would like to take the axiom of moral realism, as defined by SEP:

moral claims do purport to report facts and are true if they get the facts right. Moreover, they hold, at least some moral claims actually are true.

If I am correct, it seems that one could be a moral realist and believe that morality has no normative force, so the moral ought must be justified further, it is not entailed from moral realism.
I can think of two formulations of the normativity of morality:
1. Moral oughts, i.e. you ought to do/be x because x is morally good.
2. Rational oughts from moral facts, In as far as you ought to be rational based on non-moral facts, you ought to be rational based on moral facts, just as you act in a certain way because the sky is blue, you should act a certain way because x is wrong.
I do not accept formulation 1, for reasons articulated by many philosophers, one among them Schopenhauer:

That ought has any sense [Sinn] and meaning [Bedeutung] at all only in
relation to threatened punishment or promised reward. Thus, long before
Kant was thought of, Locke already says: ‘For since it would be utterly in
vain, to suppose a rule set to the free actions of man, without annexing to
it some enforcement of good and evil to determine his will; we must,
where-ever we suppose a law, suppose also some reward or punishment
annexed to that law.’ (On Understanding, Bk. II, ch. 33, §6). So the ought
is necessarily conditioned by punishment or reward [...]. But once those
conditions are thought away the concept of ought remains empty of
sense. (BM §4, 123)

And further arguments from this paper
I also don't accept formulation 2. Firstly, it is not clear to me that one ought to be rational 1. But even if I take the axiom that one ought to be rational, would that entail obeying the moral principles?
Rationality: the purely internal matter of having one’s mind in good order, regardless of how this matches up to external facts. As Kolodny describes it, rationality is “about the relation between your attitudes, viewed in abstraction from the reasons for them.”1
It's not clear to me that it is more rational to obey moral principles than it is not to. One can just as easily have a coherent set of beliefs that result in action that does not act in accordance with the moral truths. For example, using non-moral facts, my coherent set of beliefs could entail that I act as if the sky is not blue, if this disposition was altogether better for me. It isn't clear to me why this would be irrational.
So my questions are, have I missed any formulations for the normativity of moral beliefs, and what reasons do moral realists have for believing morality has normative force?
Further, I wonder how common it is for a moral realist to not believe it entails normative force?

On standard understanding, normativity is part of what  "moral" means. Non-normative facts are about something else (although non-moral facts could also be normative). lndeed, critics charge that moral realism forces us to accept a "queer" kind of facts, see SEP:"Moral facts place demands upon us, but (Mackie asks) how could such demands exist objectively? This would seem to require rules of conduct somehow written into the fabric of the universe, and nothing in our understanding... suggests that anything of the kind exists."

Couldn't the "reward and punishment" simply arise from the results of an action? Like the "law of gravity" is enforced by your fall from a height being arrested by the ground? It is simple and inescapable, there is no place on earth you can jump from and not be forcibly stopped. If a moral 'law' doesn't have any force, then yes, it's just wishful thinking. But most actions have effects.

If Game Theory can talk about Cooperation and Defection in the abstract, then why can't moral laws consider from the standpoint of getting along with people versus harming them? No great leap is required. Mathematics already supports it, just get the two labels correct.

@Aph002 - I'm somehow missing the point of your question. Moral "facts" are normative - they pertain to how one should act. No? Moral rules are not essentially different from the rules of a game, in this regard. "A is admirable" is equivalent to "A deserves praise" which is equivalent to "We should praise A" -- equivalent for all practical or relevant purposes.  The article you linked to seems to equivocate about "rational" (psychological coherence; being reasonable; valid inference; maximizing over preference orderings - ie self-interest).

@ScottRowe I agree that reward and punishment could arise from the result of an action, however in that case the Ought ceases to be a moral ought, which was Schopenhauer's point as I understand it. And if the only reason for doing action x is the reward/punishment, what if doing y (action that is not in accordance with moral facts) brings greater reward or no punishment? Of course, this entirely depends on what you mean by rewards/punishments, and I'm sure it could be justified within certain axiologies. That's my thinking, anyway.

@mudskipper That very interesting, In your example regarding A, I can agree that the first two claims are equivalent, but the third is not. The first two claims are descriptive, that A is admirable, and that A is praiseworthy ('Deserve' is a word that can be interpreted too loosely here, in my opinion), but those two premises are of a different sort to "We/you ought to praise A", which is a prescriptive claim.

For me, it seems to boil down to people being unwilling to do what their own mind and other minds tell them would be beneficial. Free Will amounts to just "I won't". No one argues with the Instruction Manual that comes with a piece of equipment, but unfortunately that was left out when humans are born. We could write one...

@Apph002 - So you are saying - if I understand you correctly: "There are descriptive claims. There are prescriptive claims. Prescriptive claims are not equivalent to descriptive claims, they are of a different sort. Therefore, we should not treat or consider prescriptive claims as equivalent to descriptive claims". -- Is that correct?

@ScottRowe - Reminds me of Wittgenstein's comment about ethical rules in the Tractatus (6.422): 'The first thought when an ethical law of the form "You must ..." is set up is: And what, if I don't.'

@mudskipper a good Instruction Manual explains the result of noncompliance. For example, electric hairdryers say that use in a bathtub can result in electrocution. Not that complicated. It seems that people balk at writing the manual for some reason, but that is awfully childish.

@Aph002 - I trust you saw where I was going with my question, right? Consider also "reasoning" or "logic" as the study of "valid inference". When I say "This conclusion is not logically valid", it seems to me that this implies or is equivalent to "We should not draw this conclusion (based on these premisses, etc)." The predicate "is valid" is a descriptive predicate, but it has an essentially normative (prescriptive) meaning or aspect.

And all this is also equivalent imo to statements like "You cannot draw this conclusion if you have these premisses and if you want to use these derivation rules." (Countering with "I can very well, I just did so!" means you're not playing the same game, you're not putting up a logically valid reasoning. It's like when losing a chess game after an invalid move, you'd say "I may very well do that move. I just did so!")

@mudskipper I'm unsure the truth of this example entails the second. The game example fits perfectly in the logic example, if the player wishes to play the game of logic, then they ought to accept the outcome, but the ought doesn't stem from the descriptive predicate "valid" or "invalid", but rather from the players' acceptance of the rules which themselves contain normative axioms. But to say the normativity of moral facts stems from the player's desire to play the game of morality doesn't seem to be meaningful, doesn't that only say that people who want to be moral ought to be moral?

And a further objection to the first example, I am unsure whether "A is admirable" should count as a valid moral fact, for the same reason that "A is enjoyable" surely wouldn't. Being admirable is not a fundamental property of something, it's an extrinsic attribute, I think it could be rephrased as "A is good in such a way that it could have the attribute of admirability", and now the jump to "A ought to be admired" is clearly not equivocal.

@Aph002 - I agree this all requires more careful development (though I'm convinced I'm right :) -- perhaps I'll write a blog or question/answer about it. For now however I'm not interested enough in (meta)ethics ... too much other stuff...



Rational oughts from moral facts, In as far as you ought to be rational based on non-moral facts, you ought to be rational based on moral facts, just as you act in a certain way because the sky is blue, you should act a certain way because x is wrong.


The way an ideally rational person arrives at a belief is:

They consider some evidence and arguments
Based on their current beliefs and the evidence, and based on rational standards, they decide if they would prefer to adopt some different set of beliefs proposed in the argument, instead of their current ones.
Goto 1.

The theoretical outcome of this process, after infinite repetitions - or more precisely, in the limit as all the evidence and arguments are considered - is some set of beliefs.
We would hope that this ultimate set of beliefs is the truth - or the most rational approximation to the truth as can be known from available evidence.
This same notion can be easily applied to moral truths. Theoretically, in the limit, what would the ideally rational person adopt as their belief about "I should do X"? That's a factual, well-founded question, assuming we can specify what "rational standards" the ideally rational person is applying in step 2. Specifying those standards can't be done at present, but does not seem completely impossible to do at some future point. Philosophers have been discussing what does or does not count as rational for thousands of years, and in many areas a consensus has emerged which seems objective. Cognitive science may also help reveal fundamental principles of how thought works.
So, in some sense you have your answer: what's moral is what an ideally rational person would conclude is moral if they spent forever thinking about it. As a theoretical curiosity, done and done. "Ought" has been reduced to "is."
(Although there is the possibility that the ideally rational person would in the end conclude nothing is moral or immoral, but at least that would then be an objective fact; the only moral fact.)
But although that's theoretically sound, of course it is not really enough of an answer. You want some idea of what the ideally rational person's specific beliefs would actually end up being.
Well, let me give one perspective. When we hear moral arguments, we may be persuaded to change the way that we act; we change our preferences. You learn about slaves in diamond mines in Africa, and you might be motivated not to buy diamonds mined in that way. And this subsequent motivation is better-informed, and thus in some sense simply better, than the previous one.
Preferences change when you realize what the consequences of that preference would be, and realize you do not prefer those consequences. Preferences can also change when you realize two of your preferences are inconsistent with each other; you might have "I should love my neighbor," and "I hate that guy," both in your box of preferences, not playing nice with each other. You're going to have to get rid of one of them or find some synthesis.
What would our preferences end up being, in the limit of such a process? How would the ideally rational person prefer to behave, after an infinity of contemplation? We may suppose this infinity passed in a dream, and then they opened their eyes and resumed living.
One possibility is they would desire nothing - they would be completely indifferent to all states of affairs, and if they had a human body they would die from not having any preference to eat or even breathe.
One possibility is that they would be selfish. They would care only for their own pleasure.
But a third possibility is that they would desire to act in ways that improve the world generally. They would see no reason why one single entity should be privileged over all the other entities. They would desire for the world to be more kind, just, and honest, and to strive towards greater heights of discovery, so everyone can be as enlightened as they are.
And if the third possibility happens to be the case, we would be justified in defining "morality" to be the preferences of the ideally rational being. Morality as preferences-in-the-limit. Morality as what you would want, if you knew more.

"I love you man!" Someone here finally agrees with me on this subject.

Your question is a legitimate one.  One can accept moral realism, AND reject moral behavior.  However, this is a rare position, most questioning of the derivation of "ought" question moral realism, for the reasons alluded to in the other answers.  Your focus on rationality, and its Analytic approach to philosophy, is part of the problem you are encountering.
The basic issue you have raised is that one cannot close the logical argument from facts to actions.  This is not just true of MORAL facts though.  It is true of all facts, and even of the possibility OF "facts".  One of the more important statements of the problem is the Munchausen Trilemma. Per the Trilemma, all of our justifications do not close, other than in fallacies.  See this answer on the Munchausen Trilemma.  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/64646/29339  Our justifications all break down, if questioned thoroughly enough.  Analyticity requires unquestionable "givens", and these cannot ever be found.
There is a very similar problem for reasoning itself, and logic.  Reasoning is not rational, and logic is not logical.  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/115875/29339  The existence of logical pluralism with an infinity of logics, makes "logical"  and "rational" basically meaningless terms.
The only way I know of to try to close the problem of "why do anything" is to go fully pragmatic.  Failure to respond to pragmatically likely facts, failure to apply our best guesses as to how to reason, leads to apparent catastrophe.  The babies who make this choice in their first year of life, "fail to thrive" and die young.  That same Darwinian process applies to us in adulthood.  "Failure to thrive", fatally, is the outcome of rejecting facts and reasoning -- even if we cannot rationally or logically close the loop of justifications.
there are two things that make MORAL oughts different:

there are so many disputing moral POVs, that the reality of moral oughts is actually reasonably questioned.
even if one concedes moral realism, the different natures of the proposed moral structures of our universe have pretty significant differences in how one should pragmatically respond to moral facts.

For 1) there are ways to partially justify belief in moral oughts.
Option a) IF moral objectivity is true, THEN it is reasonable that we have a moral sense to observe this objective aspect of our universe, AND we seem to have just such a sense.  Our moral sense is clearly skewable by social training, so is not purely reliable, BUT, if one identifies the characteristics of morally admired people cross culturally (cross cultural sainthood), and widely accepted cross cultural moral theories, one can identify the nature of the moral reality by the common denominator cross culturally.
Option b) IF morality is an emergent aspect of human societies, we can still identify what is essential to this "human" morality by the methods of a), to sort socially unique features from the "human" features of this emergent reality.
But even with options 1a and 1b, the details of moral thinking lead to wide differences in how one responds to moral choices, per 2).
This difference is most pronounced in the Eusocial vs. rational egoist moral stances, looking from the POV of a red blood cell near an injury.  The skin and blood cells right at an injury will kick over to their genetic programming to dry out, die, and form a scab, to try to staunch the flow of blood from an injury, and allow more interior cells to rebuild that region of a body.  There is usually not enough local cells, and more blood cells flow into the injured area and die and scab as well.  A blood cell that is a rational egoist, may recognize the benefit to the community of this process, but still seek to redirect down some distant capillary to avoid becoming part of a scab itself... Eusociality theory notes that there is a continual conflict between rational self interest and eusocial good, and when members of the community defect to rational self interest, the community suffers.  HOWEVER, for red blood cells, they will not survive the death of the communal body, but individuals humans -- sometimes DO survive the death of their community.
There is a reason the tension is higher for humans than for blood cells.  This is because the different framing of who or what is the object of moral reasoning:  individuals, individuals summed, the community, or even Gaia as the object of moral thought -- will change both the facts, and how one should pragmatically respond to them.
Rational self interest tends to be an outlier vs. other moral thinking.  But IF one treats moral facts as emergent from society rather than intrinsic, then abandoning group morality in favor of always defecting when a society is dying, then re-adopting collaborative emergent morality when a society is re-formed, makes more pragmatic sense than it does when a society is functioning.
The need to consider defecting if a society is at risk of breaking down is an evolutionary explanation for why we are more skeptical of moral realities than we are of reality and reasoning in general, despite the similarity of failures of rational justification for all of the above.

Hm - you need pretty good skills to survive on your own -- and keep your sanity.
Living in society it is generally advantageous for all parties to cooperate. This by itself creates a constant temptation to defect, and may also create (more) opportunities for opportunists, con artists, "parasites". So, we do negotiate and bargain and institute a police and a system of laws...

It's kind of heartening to see that in the Ultimate Game (https://eprints.qut.edu.au/88747/1/More%20than%20thirty%20years%20of%20ultimatum%20bargaining.pdf) one actually "spontaneously" chosen (offered and accepted) stable point is not too far from an equal split.

@mudskipper -- You are exploring the implications of eusociality being evolutionarily advantageous.  Collaborating is why humans are such a dominant species.  BUT -- for every eusocial species, there is a risk of freeloaders, those who defect only when called upon to  make major sacrifices.  How to deal with freeloaders -- yes one needs "police".  But even more useful is to put the police in their own heads -- with a superego, and moral guilt.  This, unfortunately, leads to society hijacking our moral sense, for the evolutionary benefit of the community.

Indeed. But there doesn't seem a practical way around this - we need both some internalization (moral sense) and external enforcement - At least I don't see one in our highly-interdependent-industrial society. (You could go back to small, egalitarian anarchist communities -- but there it's the group who directly polices the freeloaders or keeps them in check. Social shunning is also pretty darned effective.) The real problem is how to find balance - It would be good if philosophers tried to address that, instead of rehashing totally irrelevant abstractions ...
