The absolute truth paradox
Read before answering:
I don't want to edit the whole question because it has some interesting answers to it the way it is written now. So I will just add this as a tip before answering since many answers just point to the similarity with Russel's paradox.
I changed my "absolute truth statement" to this one:
The absolute truth: "There are no absolute truths, other than this one."
This way the paradox is resolved but I am still interested in your opinion if this modified statement of mine is somehow flawed?

Original question:
Let's say that there is no absolute truth because we as humans are restrained, (exactly because we are physical beings,) from ever knowing it because we can only make statements about the reality just by examining it subjectively.
If that is the case, then I can say "There are no absolute truths" and that would be an absolute truth; therefore I can say:
The absolute truth: "There are no absolute truths." (1)
This is also the question at hand in this questions:
All truths are relative, Comte and Relativism and Russell's paradox
So we constructed a paradox.
When trying to get out of this paradox, I came upon the idea that:
"The statement (1) is only paradoxical if we accept the axioms of classical logic."
Meaning that we shouldn't be so sure even about logical reasoning.
Question: Is this a "good" way to escape this paradox? Can we do philosophy without logical reasoning?
EDIT:
Does including the word "other" fix this contradiction?
The absolute truth: "There are no absolute truths, other than this one." (2)
Can I than set this sentence (2) as my absolute truth? It doesn't seem paradoxical now and I can use it as step zero.

"There is no absolute truth because we as humans are restrained from ever knowing it" is fallacious, what humans can know imposes no restriction on what is. And  "this" will only be a way out of the paradox after it specifies which axioms of classical logic are supposed to be dropped, and shows that what is left is enough and otherwise reasonable. There are several options described in standard treatments of the Liar paradox, of which this is a variant, see SEP, Liar.

@Conifold Ok, I agree the first sentence can be considered fallacious. It should go: "There is no absolute truth accessible to humans, because we are physical." That is exactly why I added the addendum.

@Conifold - re. "what humans can know imposes no restriction on what is." That rather depends on how 'is' is defined. Until entities are determined they are undetermined, i.e. neither existent nor non-existent. Although "Once entities have been uncovered, they show themselves precisely as entities which beforehand already were." (quote from my post below).

Nagarjuna already solved this.

@dawn Hi, could you please share what was his conclusion?

Re your "The absolute truth: "There are no absolute truths, other than this one.", it could be said that it's not paradoxical in itself, however, it's not aligned with contemporary intuitionistic constructive criterion since you haven't demonstrated why all other propositions other than this one are all false. Your hand waving argument from the  mere fact that we can only make statements about the reality just by examining it subjectively could be applied to your own master sentence too as a subjective linguistic truth value assertion, not a constructive argument if not demanding proof...

"Thou shalt have no other gods before me." ;-)

There are an infinity of different logics.  https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think/article/guide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians/EDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B12D877  These different logics have different "truth" criteria.  There is not just one logic, so whether something is "true" or not, is contingent on what logic one uses to evaluate that "truth".  And different logics provide different answers for the same case.
You are using classical logic, which we know under some circumstances ends up in cases of paradox.  Not all logicians have given up on their being a "one true logic", but their proposals for this end up being highly complex logics, that are paraconsistent as a minimum, and deviate significantly from the simplicity and clarity of classical logic.  And he advocates of a "one true logic" have not been able to converge on a single proposal, so most of them reject each other's proposals.
Under this circumstance of logic pluralism, and known flaws in classical logic, the best summary for your claim is that there is no generalized meaning across logics for the term "absolute truth" is that there is no general cross-logic meaning for the term, and no cross-logic method of evaluating assertions about it.
SO -- decomposing your statement:

The absolute truth: "There are no absolute truths, other than this one."

"There are no absolute truths" => is not a generalizable claim across logics
"other than this one" => is not a generalizable claim across logics
"The absolute truth" => is not a generalizable term or meaning across logics
The effort to create, OR refute a worldview being baseable on analytic foundations -- therefore breaks down under self-incoherence of the foundations of logic.
There is an alternative way forward, and that is to work off pragmatic truth rather than logical truth.  Under pragmatic truth, logical foundationalism may not be self-consistent, BUT it could still be a very useful framework for providing a partial foundation for a worldview.  Under pragmatic truth, that this approach is incoherent is not fatal even though it does not satisfy the truth condition of logical truth. The USE of classical logic, and logical foundationalism could still be pragmatically useful despite its self-contradictions.  Pragmatically, all our efforts to justify a worldview fail to logically close, so all our justifications are only incomplete best efforts.

Hi. Thanks for the answer. So you say: "Every effort to create (or refute) a worldview based on analytical thinking will always break down." Can I put it plastically like this: "You can not fix a wrench with that very same wrench."?

(2) what do you think about this statement: "I can't know anything for certain, not even this." It doesn't seem to form a paradox, and it seems to hold steady. What do you think?

@User198 I agree with your latest sentence.  I am a Popperian, and embrace his (and Pierce's) fallibalism and intrinsic uncertainty.  See my answer about the Munchausen Trilemma  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/64646/29339

I wrote another question on this (simmilar to this topic) that I will link that you can answer if you want. I somehow concluded it using either fallibalism or that theory based on analytic foundations should fail. It is here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/119909/consistency-and-special-pleading-in-absolute-truth-claims/119947#119947

And fallibalism seems like more and more really nice theory the more I think about it, but I am new to it. I am interested now tho; have you (or someone you discussed it with) found any flaws or encountered any "weaknesses" in that statement: "I can't know anything for certain, not even this."

It seems like a self-affirming statement instead of a self-refuting one (the ones we usually get when discussing nonexistence of absolute truth).

"Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler”:
To avoid becoming caught up in paradoxa or calculi of non-standard logic you may instead state your proposition as a hypothesis.
Then you may hold on to the hypothesis "There is no absolute truth" until it is refuted by a counter example.
Added: The second-best strategy is to avoid self-referential propositions which lead to paradoxa.

Hi, thanks for the response. But this seems like an easy way out. I don't want that. Of course I can say, the statement (1) is just a hypothesis and go on to continue walking in the park.

I don't want that kind of resolution. Seems like surrendering without much of a fight.

@User198 To me it looks as if you first invent a problem and then you complain that it's difficult to solve.

Maybe, but just because your solution just builds a safety fence around the problem. I think that it makes more sense to me to choose the regressive argument in the Münchhausen trilemma than anything else.

That is if we can see this "problem" of mine as just one more step in the regression that is present in the Münchhausen trilemma.

A hypothesis should make sense, but the lack of ontological basis for 'absolute truth' means the hypothesis is invalid.

@ChrisDegnen Which hypothesis do you mean, that is invalid?

Any hypothesis about 'absolute truth'. It might as well be an hypothesis about unicorns.

You did not construct a paradox, you did construct a proof by contradiction: As soon as you assume there are no absolute truths, you reach a contradiction - therefore there must be some absolute truth.
Of course, the real challenge is to figure out what the absolute truth actually is, not just whether it exists. It’s perfectly possible to satisfy your proof with the only absolute truth being that there is this absolute truth.

Hi. Ok I get you. But I actually think that it is a challenge even to prove that an absolute truth exists (just one). Ok if we use "only" and say: The only absolute truth is "There is no absolute truth other than this one." Than we found 1 abs. truth.

But I believe we can not find another, this is the only one.

@User198 I don't see why "There is no absolute truth other than this one." is correct. Your proof shows there is at least one, claiming there is exactly one does not follow.

But my philosophy for constructing this proof was: We can question everything and we can not know anything really, ergo: "There is no absolute truth." But than I figured out: "Hey I constructed an absolute proof with that statement." So I said: "The abs. truth:" There is no abs truth." That was my thought process.

I said there is are no absolute truths and constructed a paradox, so I wanted to resolve it here. So it's not if there is one or more, I said there is none, but the one that says there are none.

@User198 It doesn't matter what you wanted to do, you did construct a proof that there is at least one (well, technically not none). That you managed to construct one does not mean it is the only one.

Maybe there is no Absolute truth.
See also Descartes' Discourse on the Method (1637). For the purpose of practical life, we can live with a lot of "provisional certainties".
And see Aristotle, Rhet. 1355a 15–18:

For, in fact, the true and that which resembles it come under the purview of the same faculty, and at the same time men have a sufficient natural capacity for the truth and indeed in most cases attain to it.

We may be wrong about them, but we can revised them and adapt our beliefs to reality: the proof that this procedure works is in the fact that we (humans) survived.
Having said that, there are truth that are less uncertain than others: mathematics, known facts, etc.
See William James, The Meaning of the Word 'Truth' (Mind, 1908) and Pragmatism: "Both Peirce and James are associated with the slogan that: 'Truth is satisfactory to believe.' James understands this principle as telling us what practical value truth has. True beliefs are guaranteed not to conflict with subsequent experience. Likewise, Peirce’s slogan tells us that true beliefs will remain settled at the end of prolonged inquiry."
But see Hegel for "Absolute".
Wrt the question:

When trying to get out of this paradox, I came upon the idea that [we have to revise] the axioms of classical logic.

Is it really a paradox? Maybe the problem is in the "unrestricted" (absolute?) assertion. In order to avoid conundrums, we have to regiment in some way our language, avoiding self-refernce (see The Liar, more relevant here than Russell's one).
But from a methodological point of view, your proposal is exactly what I've suggested above: if needed, we have to revise our beliefs, logical principles included (see Quine's Naturalism).

Can we do philosophy without logical reasoning?

Can we "do life" without argument, dialogue, discussion? Humans are social animals living in complex social environments. Thus, some sort of "logic" is unavoidable.

Hi. Ok we can make some categories that "This is theory statement" and this is a "Metatheory statement" and only metatheories can describe theories, but theories can not describe themselves in order to avoid paradoxes.

That is exactly what mathematics did to resolve the Russel's (Liar's) paradox, but mathematics can do that because it is distinct from the reality.

There's an old joke about the fisherman who marks a favorite spot by tying a string between a rock and a stick and tossing that overboard. The rock, being pumice with gas trapped in its bubbles, floats. The stick, being ipe or another "ironwood", sinks.
Knowledge must be considered provisional, subject to refinement when we discover places it doesn't work. We may be highly confident of the answer, but we have to be aware that exceptions are possible and will modify our confidence when found. 1+1=2 except in binary where 1+1=10. You can't take a square root of a negative number -- until you introduce imaginary and complex numbers. Newton's Laws work in flat space, but needed to be refined by relativity to work in space heavily distorted by mass.
I know what I know. I also know that I can be wrong in detail, or in complete error, and will accept that when it can be demonstrated to me, adjusting my knowledge appropriately.
Absolute truths are like absolute zero temperature. Useful concept, but not something we expect to encounter in reality. Getting to almost absolute zero is the best we can hope for and in practical terms is usually good enough.
(Rephrased, thanks:)
There may be ultimate truths. But it is unlikely we will find them, or recognize them as such if we do stumble on them. You can't prove a theory will never break down; you can only show that it's the best models have now... and that statement is about as close to a perfect truth as we've got.

Seems reasonable. What kind of school of thought is this (or closest to what school)?

@user198: I'm curious about that myself. I haven't studied enough of the history to say where I fall in the established categories. Basically, this is the practical approach, suitable for scientists, engineers, and other folks who believe that absolute statements are inherently incomplete (including this one).

While re-reading your answer, I am confused with the last sentence. "You can't prove a negative; you can only show that there's nothing yet that conflicts with the positive". I don't get the second part: "you can only show that there's nothing yet that conflicts with the positive"

Do you, by positive, mean some general positive statement or do you explicitly mean that the positive is: "There exists an absolute truth." ?

@User198: Good catch, that formulation is no longer current. Thank you for the correction. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)#:~:text=Proving%20a%20negative,-A%20negative%20claim

See also the other issues covered on that page. Some of them overlap strongly with recent discussions here.

Yes thanks, I was also reading that wiki when pondering your answer. I agree that it is extremely hard to prove negative, but in the case of my statement: "There are no absolute truths, other than this one.". Idk if that statement if a positive or negative anymore. Since it declares an existence of an absolute truth by a negative statement. I asked that question in the chat, because I don't want to crowd this question.


Let's say that there is no absolute truth because we as humans are restrained, (exactly because we are physical beings,) from ever knowing it

Facts can be absolutely true regardless of whether any human knows them. What is the case, and what humans think is the case, are two different things.
Quoting from a comment you made:

There is no absolute truth accessible to humans, because we are physical.

Humans can believe things that happen to be true, even though they don't have certainty in that knowledge. Isn't that a form of access to truth? Most of what a human believes - 2+2=4, there are elephants in Africa, steel is denser than wood - is in fact true. There's no perfect certainty that it is true, but nonetheless, it is true, and we believe it, and we have well-justified reasons for believing it.
It seems as if you're using "absolute truth" to mean "absolutely certain truth," but they are not the same thing. "Absolute truth" is about the truth itself, and "absolutely certain truth" is about our level of knowledge of the truth.

Hi, yes it may be that my expressions are not rigorously defined. I am not a trained philosopher. To make it clearer, I am not interested about empirical truths, but instead in truths that are sought to be proven/disproven within the domains of epistemological skepticism and closely related fields.

There is a common theme in 20th century philosophy that reacts skeptically to problems of philosophy that are just word games. In fact, there's a widely used term for what you are doing and thinking: pseudo-problem. In the 1920's, the bright mind of Rudolf Carnap wrote a book on it called The Logical Structure of the World and Pseudoproblems in Philosophy (GB). Later, Ludwig Wittgenstein, the latter and better version of himself, attacked such word games as just exercises in misunderstanding about the purpose and proper use of language. Richard Rorty is another critic, a self-described neo-pragmatist, who attacks the cliche of the endless stream of "making" and "solving" paradoxes.
To cut some corners, you are simply created yet another self-referential paradox. Roughly, you are simply taking the form "Given there is X: where X is there are no X's" and repackaging it. The reason Conifold created a link to the SEP article Liar Paradox is because "your" solution can be built in the same way most logician resolve the more classical paradoxes.
You ask:

Question: Is this a "good" way to escape this paradox? Can we do philosophy without logical reasoning?

So, this is a technically adequate way to resolve the paradox in terms of formal logic, but is it "good"? It is if you've learned something about the technicalities of paradoxes. As for can we do philosophy without reasoning, the consensus is overwhelmingly that philosophy leans heavily on reasoning and logic for its method, so one could go about simply relying on intuition to make assertions, but philosophy has always cultivated the impulse to make sure ideas don't have contradictions. The question of exactly what philosophy "should" do generally falls under the umbrella of metaphilosophy.

Hi. Yes through this this question I learned about Wittgenstein, seems like a really cool guy. Going to the library to borrow Tractatus and Philosophical investigations any day now.

I tried to fix the statement by saying: "There are no absolute truths, other than this one." in order to avoid it from being just another form of Liar's paradox. Do you think that fixes the problem?

And yes, I am not interested in the empirical truths, or that kind of reasoning. I was trying to come up with some metatheory that can be the zero starting point as the 1 absolute truth, because we can question every truth someone presents us with.

And by labeling this problem as a "pseudoproblem" because it is a word game, isn't than every topic in philosophy a word game? Because words don't represent facts, they are just words, but we communicate philosophy with others by words.

Your solution works for me. Sounds like you got a plan. Tractatus is LW's logical atomism. He recanted after thinking things over, and later LW set the Sprachspiel in motion. If you wade through his meandering thoughts, I"d recommend moving on to relevance theory. Then jump to Philosophy and the Mirror. The circle back with Quine et al.

On the upside, your paradox (and all of the others) precipitated Tarskian semantics and mathematical logic, and the useful distinction between object and meta-language can't be understated.

Thanks for the references. Will look into it.

Oh, and if you're trying to find absolute truths, you're doing foundationalism. Descartes wound up with the Cogito. Maybe you'll start somewhere else. The much more popular epistemological position today is fallibilism, which strikes at the heart of "absolute" anything.

Well, I was actually trying to do the opposite. I was actually trying to disprove the existence of any absolute truths, and by doing that I stumbled on "the one" absolute truth: "There are no absolute truths, other than this one." Yes, Decartes wanted a simmilar thing, but he wanted to prove a positive, while I tried to disprove all positives.

@User198 Oh, well then you're in good company. "Absolute truth" would have to be a truth in a particular theory of truth. It would certainly beg the question 'which theory accommodates the notion of the 'absolute truth' as a species?' If you find yourself struggling to situate 'absolute truth' in a successful theory, so too will your opponent.

Would you say that Socrates was doing a similar thing when stating: "Scio me nihil scire". That that was his only truth: "I know nothing." I am asking because it seems that he was so on point so early because many of the much later philosophers are still pondering the same thing. It is similar to Arcimedes stating the Riemann hypothesis  a early as 200 BC, stating such a profound question so early. What do you think?

Absolutely foundationalist. There is one thing I know and that is I know nothing. One removes the contradiction by situating the first know in a meya-language. And the second know in an object language.  There was a post about this specifically 6 mos(?) ago. You can also embrace dialethia. True contradictions are okay by way of a non-classical logic.


I am human
I am not human
There is a God
There is no god

Four statements, two false and two absolutely true.  And I just made another absolutely true statement.  The inability of proving which doesn't change the facts.
Many more examples are possible.  "X is Y" & "X is not Y" for any values of X and Y.

Hi. I don't think you get what I mean when saying "absolutely true". I am not denying empirical, tautological and similar truths. I am saying that you can question everything, even your "absolute truth: "I am human.". To that, I can say, how can you be so sure? Maybe you are just a spontaneous interaction of electrons that produced a brief simulation somewhere in the universe (and you experience that as your life (that is the Boltzmann brain thought experiment)), or you can maybe be just some jellyfish and not human really.

So I don't think you managed to construct an absolute truth with your examples.

The same goes for the rest of your statements: " I am not human. " I say : " How can you be so sure?" "There is God?" How can you be so sure? There is no God?"  How can you be so sure?

I don't see any absolute truth in your examples.

Of course you can question it.  But your questions cannot change true to false or vice versa.  And to "How can I be sure?" I repeat: it doesn't matter whether I am sure or skeptical, neither can make it true nor make it false.

Yes, neither can make it true nor false. But why call than your statement an "absolute truth" I think that is not a proper name for something that can be questioned.

Then I guess you and I have differing definitions of "absolute."

@User198 If you think none of those statements can be "absolute truths" because you can doubt them, then "There are no absolute truths (except this one)" is also not an absolute truth, because I doubt it. There are lots of other statements like, "I think therefore I am," or "0+0 = 0" that could potentially be absolute truths, therefore your statement is unsure, therefore it cannot be an absolute truth, therefore it is false.

The revised assertion ("there are no absolute truths other than this one") is not inherently inconsistent.
But one other absolute truth would be enough to falsify it.
I'm personally sure that another absolute truth can be found. The preceding sentence may be one. I'm not interested enough to search for others, or to defend this one. For me, it suffices to point out that taking any absolute position, as opposed to saying "probably" or "as far as I / we know" or something of that sort, risks setting yourself up for failure.
I prefer "Absolutes are always inherently false. Including this one."

Heidegger makes observations on truth with the example of Newton's laws.  While Heidegger's earlier ideas on truth focused on 'uncoveredness' he subsequently agreed on truth as correspondence of assertion with evidence.  So Newton's 2nd law of motion before it was proved was merely the assertion F = ma, which was found to be true by experimentation and observation.  In this way truth depends on the person establishing a truth.

Newton's laws, the principle of contradiction, any truth whatever
—these are true only as long as Dasein is. Before there was any
Dasein, there was no truth; nor will there be any after Dasein is no
more. For in such a case truth as disclosedness, uncovering, and
uncoveredness, cannot be. Before Newton's laws were discovered, they
were not 'true'; it does not follow that they were false, or even that
they would become false if ontically no discoveredness were any longer
possible. Just as little does this 'restriction' imply that the
Being-true of 'truths' has in any way been diminished.
To say that before Newton his laws were neither true nor false, cannot
signify that before him there were no such entities as have been
uncovered and pointed out by those laws. Through Newton the laws
became true; and with them, entities became accessible in themselves
to Dasein. Once entities have been uncovered, they show themselves
precisely as entities which beforehand already were. Such uncovering
is the kind of Being which belongs to 'truth'.
That there are 'eternal truths' will not be adequately proved until
someone has succeeded in demonstrating that Dasein has been and will
be for all eternity. As long as such a proof is still outstanding,
this principle remains a fanciful contention which does not gain in
legitimacy from having philosophers commonly 'believe' it. GA2 p.269


Ok, but I want to make a distinction from absolute truths and empirical truths. The Newton's laws are empirical truths and I am not denying that. I am curious about absolute truths.

The conclusion that "We will never have a conclusion until Dasein is proven" means that we will never have conclusion because Dasein will never be proven. Why? Because if it were proven someone would ask "Why is Dasein like that?" and than we just pushed the question one step further.

@User198 How could an absolute truth exist? What sense of existence could found such a thing?

I am not trying to describe absolute truth. Just trying to prove/disprove the existence.

Truth's dependence on Dasein (e.g. a person, Newton) demonstrates that 'absolute truth' is simply a fanciful notion so there is no paradox.

But what makes you (not you per se, but Heidegger) so sure that Dasein exists. Abs. truths would require Dasein to exist for all eternity to continuously uncover and validate them. Ok that is one philosophy.

Take a look at my addendum. One can question "Can absolute truths exist even if they will never be accessible to human?" You imply the existence of Dasein as the connection between humans and abs. truth. But maybe abs. truths can exist independently of humans.

Re. how one knows that Dasein exists? Heidegger follows the logic of Descartes with a significant modification: "If the 'cogito sum' is to serve as the point of departure for the existential analytic of Dasein, then it needs to be turned around, and furthermore its content needs new ontologico-phenomenal confirmation. The 'sum' is then asserted first, and indeed in the sense that "I am in a world". " B&T 211 – as discussed here.

Heidegger's remarks on eternal Dasein are not very serious considering how importantly Dasein's being-towards-death features in Being & Time. Ideas on the absolute come from Plato's supersensory world of perfect forms which Nietzsche so took issue with, e.g. "Plato, for instance, when he persuaded himself that "the good," as he wanted it, was not Plato's good, but "the good in itself," the eternal treasure which a certain man of the name of Plato had chanced to find on his way!" Will to Power 972.

Godel created a formal system specifically designed to force a contradiction by using illegitimate nonterminating recursive definition.
You're doing the exact same thing here, only using simpler symbols in shorter strings.
Let's cut out the middle man and just assert that T=F! Then we can stare in  wonder at this paradox.
Existence not only precedes essence, existence IS essence. There isn't anything else. In particular, there is no meaning.1
And there aren't any paradoxes!

1 You create your own meaning. Read Nietzsche.

Hi. I added an edit in my question in order for it not to be a Russel's paradox. There are already several answers that adress that. Now the statement is: "There are no absolute truths, other than this one." So there is no paradox anymore, just "the one" absolute truth.

And I think that refined statement holds, It is not a paradox anymore, and it a pretty strong statement, at least I can not find a flaw in its logic.


So there is no paradox anymore, just "the one" absolute truth == Bah! Mere sophistry! I'll agree, there is no paradox! All you've done is concatenate symbols and assign it a truth-functional value. Which is to say, you really haven't done anything.


@MissUnderstands From the mouth of babes! Later LW would be proud. ; )

I don't know if you get what I was trying to do. I am not trying to prove or find any "meaning". I think life has no meaning (of course you can create your own if you want to). I was trying to disprove the possibility that we will ever be able to find "an absolute truth" (because you can question everything), and than I stumbled on that truth: "That there is no absolute truth, other than this one.".  Of course you can say "You are just concatenating simbols, but they don't mean anything."

But that statement can be said about anything and than what is the point of even talking or thinking about anything, it could all not make sense. But as I heard Wittgenstein was advocating a similar point so will look into it for sure.

Hi. I get that you are saying that my statement is nonsense or trivial. The thing I don't get is how did you came to that conclusion. Could you maybe explain your reasoning for that a little bit more clearly?
