How does continental philosophy cope with problems that are present in analytical philosophy
I've learned that analytic philosophy doesn't seem to offer any absolute truths (every logical theory (trying to construct an absolute truth) is doomed to fail because of self-incoherence of the foundations of logic; Gödel's incompleteness theorems, Münchhausen trilemma).
Fallibilism seems to be the best case scenario we can get from analytical philosophy, it suggests everything is open to inquiry, but it's more a pragmatic tool than a constructive theory.
So now I see philosophy as only either an activity for pragmatic truth or an activity for pleasure. Before I thought that it was possible to establish some absolute truth using (analytical) philosophy.
Does continental philosophy aim to construct theories of absolute truth? Does it face the same logical issues as analytic philosophy, like paradoxes and incompleteness? How does continental philosophy approach the quest for truth differently (if it searches for it)?

What do you mean by "self-incoherence of the foundations of logic"? - Who says that fallibilism "suggests everything is open to inquiry"? IMO that critical position is a characteristic of philosophy in general. - Which specific works of philosophy do you consider "continental philosophy"? - Please clarify the question; thanks.

There is no self-incoherence in the foundations of logic.

Some continental philosophy such as Derrida's don't aim to construct theories of absolute truth, on the contrary, aim to deconstruct theories and meanings to their possibly Platonic root via differance in the foggy and heavy mist of simulacra and simulations...

Continental philosophy approaches the world in very different ways. It is more holistic, big picture oriented, it embraces bold speculation and favors creativity of ideas over bean counting and technical precision, it is less preoccupied with epistemological obstructions. But if you are looking for 'absolute truth' you are out of luck. You can find grant metaphysical schemes there that their authors (profess to) believe are sketches of 'absolute truth' (Badiou's set ontology or Meillassoux's OOO), but not the 'establishing' of that. Both sides of the divide are apples from Kant's tree.

Husserl was, perhaps, the last major philosopher who believed that 'absolute truth' and "apodictic certainty" are achievable in philosophy. Like Kant, he is respected on both sides of the divide, even as they both decline to follow him on this score. But you may find his Philosophy as Rigorous Science congenial.

@DavidGudeman I said that having the incompletness theorems in mind, and also Münchhausen trilemma. Some examples are: The absolute truth paradox. See this question: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/119826/the-absolute-truth-paradox

The incompleteness theorems have nothing to do with incoherence; they just show that meaning can't be reduced to syntax. The Munchhausen trilemma has nothing to do with coherence or specifically with logic; it's just a particular expression of something that every scholar figures out as soon as he starts to think about foundations. It's a high-school sophomore level observation. The so-called absolute-truth paradox is not a paradox; it's just an example of a self-defeating statement that is not self-contradictory.

@DavidGudeman So you think that some sort of statement or a theory that would be "absolutely true", or would in it self contain a statement that is absolutely true, can be constructed using a logical basis?

No, I think that logic doesn't claim to produce absolute truth or even define what "absolute" means in that context, and that what you are actually noting is not a problem of logic but a problem of the human condition, namely that there is no certainty, and there are no incorrigible propositions.

@DavidGudeman Agreed. I thought that logic was able to produce absolute truth claims. I realized that it wasn't. That is what I meant when I said: "every logical theory (trying to construct an absolute truth) is doomed to fail because of self-incoherence of the foundations of logic", i.e. that an absolute truth is not even a well defined statement in a logical system. I should have explained that sentence better. Thank you for your comments.

@User198 Logic and mathematics do produce some absolute truth claims. I suspect you might say that "2+2=4" is not an absolute truth claim. But the claim "It is provable in Peano arithmetic, using the rules of inference of classical logic, that 2+2 is equal to 4" seems to be an absolute truth claim. This claim even has the virtue of being true. Another point: you mention Goedel's incompleteness theorems. These are about logical systems which can interpret Peano arithmetic. Some more primitive systems of arithmetic, like Presburger arithmetic, are provably complete and consistent.

The difference between Continental and Anglophone philosophy (analytic philosophy is a major school in the Anglophone tradition) is essentially a disagreement over the essential method of philosophy:

Continental thinkers are rationalists: holding that the proper method of philosophy involves reasoned inspection and introspection to argue for the necessity of postulates.
Anglophone thinkers are empiricists: holding that the proper method of philosophy demands careful testing of postulates against the perceptual world.

The divide isn't as harsh in practice as it is in theory; in practice empiricists necessarily use some rationalist methods and rationalists try to conform to the perceptual world. But the theoretical divide is tied to the efforts of the empirical sciences to break away from religious and speculative ideation — which are often miscast as rationalist positions — and has some bitter edges to it.
Such is life…
The concept of 'absolute truth' is dicey at best, and we should approach it cautiously. For instance, it's not at all clear that rationalists and empiricists would agree on what 'absolute truth' means. The former would be looking for truths about human nature and 'beingness', while the latter would expect conformance to some perceivable ontological structure. But in any case, philosophy doesn't specifically look to find absolute truth. Instead, philosophy assumes that truth of some sort — likely ineffable truth — exists, and philosophy's object is to understand or model it as best possible. This becomes a bit more complex in Continental philosophy, where truth is often associated with the nature of man as a moral agent, as opposed to the mere conformance to empirical observations sought in Anglophone philosophy. But the point is we can't think of truth as a goal in philosophy, but more as a project or programme.
There's nothing wrong with doing philosophy for the fun of it, or for some practical (teleological) end. But the heart of philosophy has always been seeking out the better side of the human condition. If what you're doing isn't reaching for a better self or a better world, then it's only philosophy-lite. And if you don't care about a better self or a better world, then you'll probably have no interest in philosophy at all.

So continental tries to do philosophy from within, and the anglophone tries to do it from without. (I tried to put it in my own words, I hope it makes sense.) Do you have any recommendations for a first encounter with continental philosophy book? Do you think continental is maybe more abstract than analytical philosophy?

@User198: Continental Philosophy is quite broad and diverse (much more so than Anglophone philosophy), so unless you have a specific area of interest your best bet would be to take a survey course on the subject. There are probably survey texts out there too, if you want to self study, but you need something broad and superficial to get your feet wet before you really dive in.
