A basic question about morality in the present day
I'm 18 years old, and as would be expected, I'm heavily influenced by the people around me. I mean literally persuaded by things like, "That is the correct way to think."
I don't even need to mention those stereotypical thoughts, like doing something to someone else even if it would negatively affect me. This kind of mindset can be quite dangerous for me in the long run.
My mom, for example, advises me to stop complaining about everything in my life that I can't control, but at the same time, she complains about even the smallest things that make her storm out.
The point is, looking at our actually hypocritical society (and I'm not excluding myself), it seems that the global population is dumbing down, with decreasing focus on reasoning and empiricism. Wouldn't that be controversial, considering that our past philosophers, over more than 2400 years, filled even the largest libraries with vast knowledge in philosophy, sociology, science, politics, religion, and all that stuff?  Is my sense of this true?
Also, is modern civilization, and by saying this I include social justice warriors, destroying the fundamental meaning of the word "morality" by losing the profound sense that made Plato spend years reflecting alongside Aristotle and Socrates?

What does dumbing down of the population have to do with destroying the meaning of morality? The population could be smarting up and destroying it just the same, morality and intelligence are two different things. And "what do you think" questions are off-topic here, could you rephrase it less subjectively?

Why don't you include the advocates of christofascism along with the SJWs among the destroyers of morality? Also, one should always remember that if they lived in the time of Socrates they would probably have been a slave.

Flagging as close for pushing a personal philosophy--I think bringing up "social justice warriors" and "my mom complaining" kinda... makes this question seem like it's more pushing personal complaints than a more general philosophy question. Maybe it could be edited to be more clear about what the question is?

Just study some Psychology along with Philosophy. Physics comes between the two, unfortunately. Don't get mired in the 3 R's: Rationality, Reality, Religion...

To all close voters -- it was amazingly simple to remove the request for opinions, and recast as a question about sociological facts.  SE policy is to edit rather than close a question which it is simple to bring into site compliance.

@Dcleve I wonder if you're familiar with Mr. Bumble from Dickens Oliver Twist? Ideally teachers need to (1) teach and correct (2) evaluate (3) grade (4) filter out the hopeless cases. In decreasing order of priority. The Mr. Bumbles only punish and tighten the screws of the in group. Unfortunately they tend to win out out here. And I can bet this comment will "be disappeared" within 24 hours.

In the more enlightened education systems — Socrates to Montessori — "correct" would have priority over "teach" in the sense that the subject matter is very much in the student's ambit of choice. Correction however may be required in the sense of putting a derailed approach/methodology back on track. Here instead we put closing first at the faintest trace of unsophistication

Recommend of putting an actual question in the title, preferably only one.

First, allow me to point out that human intelligence is a spectrum. There always has been (and always will be) a variance in capacity for analytic thought; that's just normal. I'd even argue that average human intelligence has increased in the last few hundred years, and continues to increase. But that's all largely irrelevant. Even the least intellectually gifted people are capable of sound reasoning (and sound moral reasoning) about most things. When people talk about 'intelligence' in that glowing, rarified sense they really mean 'creative intelligence', which is a bit of a different nut to crack. Not everyone can paint like Rembrandt, write, like Hemingway, philosophize like Thoreau, or analyze like Einstein, this is true. But almost everyone can appreciate and understand the essence of Rembrandt, Hemingway, Thoreau, and Einstein, and use that understanding for whatever practical purposes they might find in their lives. Even those people we might (pejoratively) consider 'dumb' are more than adequately intelligent if given the chance to be.
The problem we face in the modern world is an set of communications issues:

Everyone in the modern world has a megaphone, and it's far easier to use that megaphone to shout out one's momentary ideas, urges, and feelings than to put out anything intellectually substantive or creative. Even 200 years ago the only way to get hold of a public megaphone was to carefully craft something into a book, or into a speech that someone else thought worthy of writing down. The modern world is a bit like having uncontrolled ESP: we don't just hear what we want to hear; we're forced to hear every dumb, idle, random thought in everybody else's head, all at once. It can be disconcerting.
Our political systems have an unfortunate tendency to disincentivize thought and reason. People who use reason are liable to act in ways which political figures can't predict and may not like; people who thoughtlessly react on an emotional level are both predictable and controllable, which is much more to a politician's liking. So we tend to get barraged from the political class with desperate emotional pleas, wildly aggressive posturing, rapid shifts in focus, stubborn refusals to be clear or make sense, etc, all to keep the system in a state of confounded tension where people tend to react more than act.
Our economic systems particularly disincentivize moral reasoning. Our economics demands competitive self-interest, and within the modern megaphonic communications world we live in that translates to a constant and almost feral demand for attention. People want views, likes, up-votes, subscriptions, etc, because those translate to status that can be monetized. And given the intense pressure of millions of megaphones using the same modalities, many people are less concerned with what their influencer status means (i.e., its moral standing) than with the influencer status itself. Click-bait has more bite than think-bait, and so most of what blasts across our screens is aimed at organs a good bit lower than the brain.

All in all, the world isn't any less intelligent or moral than it used to be — quite the opposite, in fact — but our communication system tends to put the least intelligent and moral aspects on full blast. It used to be that we could see the intellectual creators of the world and more or less ignore everyone else; now we have a hard time ignoring everyone who feels like cranking up their own personal volume. We're no stupider than we were, but now we're forced to see the stupid side of ourselves in full living color. And that's maybe a good thing. Sure, it's painful to see that unsavory side of humanity because it disrupts our idealized notions about ourselves. But self-acknowledgement is the first step towards wisdom…

I believe you are mostly referring to the united states and some western countries regarding "morality is decreasing overtime" and that you are focused on the social justice warriors (SJW) that are quite common today, especially online. But you also have mentioned almost opposite ends of the spectrum of intent. Which we can't ignore... (well you can, but at your peril)

It is quite common that people will tell you to "not do XYZ" but they are actually doing "XYZ" all the time. The common term for this is a "hypocrite", which in modern use is very negative. However there are two other things to consider here.

They might be avoiding dealing with this action/behavior in themselves. So this could be un/conscious projecting about themselves onto you. As they are quick to latch onto their own faults in others.

They might be aware of what they are doing, and fundamentally unhappy with themselves but not willing (or able) to do anything about it. They don't want you to experience what they are experiencing, so they really don't want you to be like them.


And then you must take into account the context and relationship of the person you are dealing with. Your mother is probably trying to help you, it is unlikely that she is "out to get you" in the same way a SJW typically tends to attempt.

Regarding society "dumbing down"... I don't agree this is true. On the grandest scale possible I think in the past, there definitely would have been some crazy self proclaimed demigod that would have bathed the world in nuclear winter out of spite, and currently while the global situation is tense... no one is doing that. Even the dictators that setup cults around themselves are not doing that.
On the smaller scales, which is what you are more likely to be interested in, people are struggling to determine what is the right way to behave and live. I see many people going into destructive and positive directions. I believe it will balance out in the long run.

Regarding the SJW: From what I can see common behaviors are generally negative and are based on a sense of moral superiority. They feel it is their "duty" to go out and protest, and they pick popular issues to do this about. ("Just stop oil" for example)

They surround themselves with others who think the same as they do, this prevents them from receiving honest feedback about their opinions as well as making it difficult for them to exchange basic ideas with others. (They exist in an echo chamber so to speak)


I believe this is the most self destructive behavior they exhibit. They shut themselves off from the possibility of acquiring new information or perspectives.


The ostracization of people they dislike (Ex. cancel culture).
The weaponization of "positive emotions" for negative outcomes. (Similar to how a compassionate mother bear will maul you to death)
The lack of forgiveness for their own members (Ex. SJW will get canceled themselves).

Ultimately I do not believe the majority of the SJW are likely to feel fulfilled in the long term, this is because they are attempting to solve problems without a practical solution (Ex. We cannot just stop using oil, logically we need a plan first) and because they are focused outwards and rarely seem to improve themselves. (Because everyone else is the problem, I recycle, I do the right thing... etc)

The self righteous person has existed for longer then the SJW has it is simply a modern version of that. It's even a stereotype of the average German person, who will get in your business telling you what to do. Even though they do not know why you are jaywalking, perhaps you're running to see your baby being born? They don't know or care, they care about being "right" in a legalistic fashion. The letter of the law, not the spirit of the law.


Ultimately, as was mentioned in the comments you are responsible for your choices and actions. However as you are actively asking, I will dare to suggest a "proper way to think" and I would recommend a Jungian and existentialist attitudes toward your life. Possibly throw some Jordan Peterson into the mixture as well.
Jungian, because if you understand yourself (the shadow) you can do your best to avoid mistakes and forgive yourself when you do mess up. The story of Bert Kreischer on the russian train explaining how he prepared to never cheat on his wife, but never prepared himself to not rob a train is an example of what I mean here by "your shadow". (I believe you can find a lecture/course on youtube called Jung's Copernican Revolution if you search for it.)
Existentialism, because nihilism is depressing and awful. In existentialism everything you do has meaning. Try your best to do everything you can with purpose and intent. For information on this type of thinking I recommend searching for Friedrich Nietzsche, but there are others as well.
J.B.Peterson, his focus on "speaking the truth, or at least don't lie" is a good one to follow to help you avoid making mistakes in your life. Or perhaps that bit about "Treat yourself as if you were someone that you were responsible for taking care of" ... You can find much information in his maps of meaning lecture series on youtube, or in his other lectures.

Peace be with you

The problem is... the question is subjective, so only a subjective answer really fits into place here. But I hope the OP will look into some mental foundations that are robust and able to help them move forward in life.

@ScottRowe I didn't call western culture weird did I? I don't see it in my answer, :S

@ScottRowe Honestly, it is a perspective issue. Western culture seems to be one of the better ones, far eastern seems reasonable as well, there are however subsets in both that are absolutely awful.

Clearly yes.
One of my most brilliant teachers — top of mensa — said to me:

All my life I've tried to make the creme de la creme (in CS). Microsoft beat me to it: Now everyone uses a computer.
And now powerpoint is the paragon of "dumbed down"

He said this to me some 15 years ago which was some 20 years after my student days.
Today MS might be replaced by Google.
Or chatGPT.
I guess each innovation makes it possible for people to pretend brighter and continue dumber.

Specific advice to an 18 year old.
Firstly, I applaud you for your question.
And then earnestly request you: Love your mother however impossible the task may seem.
A conversation with the mystic teacher G.I. Gurdjieff:

Gurdjieff: You must love your mother... you must treat your father as God.
Disciple: But what if my mother is very bad?
Gurdjieff: Even if mother is merde (French for shit) must love mother.

A more lighthearted version from Mark Twain:

When I was 14 I thought my father an utter fool. When I became 21 I was amazed at how much the old man had learnt in 7 years


Right, Love should be orthogonal to Judgement. The definition of love from the Catechism is: "To Will The Good Of Another". It can be tough to get Judgment to release its claws once it has caught something though. But yeah, trying to be great at something or have an impact in a very large world is not too likely, speaking as a programmer.

@ScottRowe Parents are a fundamentally different category from the rest of humanity. You may remember the buddhist story of Angulimala, a super violent dacoit who had killed 999 victims and was about to kill his 1000th who happened to be his mother. Buddha divined this and the ethical fact that this murder would be accrue a larger karma than the 999 earlier ones So he set out to stop him.

One of the biggest differences between the secular pov and the religious one (on which all religions agree to a remarkable degree) is that the relation of a being to its parents is asymmetric : Without my parents I could not exist, without me at most they wouldn't be parents — not even that if I have siblings

@ScottRowe As to judgement, it's really simple in Christianity ( Absolutely no one follows it is another matter  ) (1) Judge not lest you be judged ( Blessed are the meek) — NT (2) Vengeance is mine — OT (ie Yahweh's so in a strictly dualistic setup it cannot be ours ie humans')

Excellent point.
First, what are morals? Morals are the set of rules that a human group agrees to in order to interact constructively. In other words, it is a set of rules that enable (or at least increase the probabilities of) survival of the group.
For example, a small group will normally forbid killing people inside the group, which is just logical. Killing decreases the survival probabilities of the group. Problems between members should be solved in any other way than killing the other.
Morals are subjective. That is, every group has different morals. Following the example, it could be bad to kill the other in a small group, but it could be allowed in larger groups. So, there is not an universal moral rule. Some groups embrace the notion of carrying weapons (not only nations but also groups like gangs), others don't.
Who determines which are the best morals for the group survival? Nature, by means of natural selection. If a group discourages heterosexual couples and encourages forming homosexual-based families, soon the group will decrease in size and vanish. For some gangsters, loyalty is essential, for others, it is useless.
Morals are informal rules, that is, non-written, accorded implicitly between its members. As seen, morals tend to follow logic, which is consistent with survival. So, in final terms, morals would be consistent with science.
However, every member could reason differently. So, morals need to be formalized, that is what a constitution is, what, law and justice are: formal rulesets that raise from morality. However, since in practice laws are written by a small group, they could be inconsistent with morals, since they imply an interpretation of a group with particular, not common interests.
If morals tend to follow logic, religion is the opposite: it is not necessarily logical. A lack of Logic always implies self-destruction.
OK, that is what morals are about.
Now, for your observation: dumb people are contrary to logic and morals: absolutely correct. When surviving becomes easy due to the group protection, the individual loses the knowledge required for own and group survival, and morals conflict with his ideas. So, morals tend to vanish, and in the long term, the group tends to vanish as well. I personally think that logic rules survival, and this mechanism could be nature's way to keep an ecological balance: excessively productive groups should become destructive. That's been observed in laboratories as a common pattern: animals in large groups interacting tend to enter in a behavioral pattern that leads to the dissipation of the group. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_sink.
Of course, the inconsequence of knowledge becomes patent. The individual who survives without effort in a large group does not need of philosophy or any other kind of knowledge. He can survive knowing just trivial stuff. Socialism and feminism are examples of knowledge that conflict with traditional morals and survival. Otherwise, there would exist large groups of socialists or feminist people flourishing. Socialist countries tend to dissipation into hard capitalism. Feminism is condemned to the same.
Another example. Clearly, homosexuality conflicts with classical morals, for an evident reason: homosexuality prevents reproduction.
Paraphrasing Socrates, the intelligent learns from everything, while the idiot has already all the answers.

My friend once told me a vision he had called The Golden Frog. He was sitting by a pond in the Northeast when a golden frog appeared on sunny rock. The frog said, "I live in two worlds". Then it turned black and jumped into the pond. Later I asked him the meaning of the two worlds. He said, "What is said and done; and what is felt and meant." This maps to what we call descriptive versus normative language. When the self or others say and do things (descriptive) the self also experiences ethical and moral judgments (normative). We compare what is said and done to our counterfactual inner drama.
Thomas Szasz wrote a book called The Myth of Mental Illness. In his model of drama, when a person complains, it means they are in some state of pain. He maps complaints to social roles. Children in pain complain to their parents or authority figures. People in pain complain to medical doctors, to lawyers, courts, and other social justice workers, and to psychiatrists and psychotherapists.
In an authoritarian regime certain types of complaints are punished. A person living in such a regime once said, "Complain and get your head bashed in." The people living in such a regime have more reason to comlain and less permission to do so. This type of situation can put a susceptible person into a psychological double-bind. Children raised by authoritarian adults in a "free" society have double-bind drama.
Complaints in the social context can be functional or effective ways to seek help in the context of human drama. Doctors may be able to identify medical disease or injury and provide a remedy. Social justice workers may at times provide an effective remedy for victims of present or past injustice. Therapists are sometimes effective at providing a remedy for suffering that is not caused by medical disease or by present social injustice. In therapy, Szasz argues, there is no such thing as mental illness. There are only people who complain about their own behavior or the behavior of others. And there are interpretations of the meaning of behavior which is more like the traditions of religion or law than the practice of medicine.
In the context of drama some people constantly complain about the behavior of others but find no fault with their own behavior. Others find fault primarily with the self and with their own behavior. The children of a perfectionist who finds fault mostly with others are in danger of imitating this pattern or of finding much fault with the self. My primary problem with psychotherapy is that the diagnosing of disorders is a fault-finding operation which is a dramatic reenactment of early life drama wherein the authorities have the power to find fault with children and inferiors in the workforce, etc. Psychotherapy is not the practice of medicine although we do associate our emotional states with the gain or loss of vitality - the ability to live.
The ethical and moral character of the world is ultimately a figment of each person's imagination based on memories of interactions with others in the world. The point is not to negate or invalidate ethical and moral judgment, but rather, to recognize that how each person relates to the world of human affairs is primarily a psychological adaptation based on one's past and present drama. I don't know the originator of this well-known saying: The optimist claims we live in the best of all possible worlds and the pessimist agrees!

There is a phenomenon you have noticed, and it is a widespread decline in trust in "reasoning".
For several hundred years, the Enlightenment values promoted reasoning as a method to achieve both technical and societal improvements.  The dominant movement in philosophic thought was an alliance of rationalism, scientific empiricism, and ethics.
That alliance of perspectives broke down early in the 20th century, and there were a lot of different reasons for this.
Rise of Physicalism
Dualism and Idealism were the dominant philosophic ontologies until the 20th century, but materialisms child physicalism became the dominant ontology beginning early in the 20th century.
Physics, which physicalism tries to reduce everything in the world to, has no VALUES.  So there is no particularly coherent way to integrate ethics into a physicalist worldview.  Additionally, many physicalists deny selfhood, agency, and free will, each of which further breaks the tie between scientific rationalism and ethics.
Science is not rational
Hume, way back several centuries ago, pointed out that empiricism isn't rational.  We can't rationally justify why something that has happened 99 times, will happen again on the 100th try.
Karl Popper recast science as more complex than just experimental replication, with his focus on Conjectures, searches for refutations, and then hypothesis revision. But Popper's recast version of science is still capable of leading to wrong conclusions.  Science is often wrong, and then a few decades later a paradigm shift is needed to correct the error. But this process is not guaranteed to improve our understanding.  Popper tried to show that it would, that a successive series of "wrong' hypotheses would have increasing "verisimilitude".  But his proof had an error, and upon correction, the calculation does not close. Science COULD just lead us further and further astray!
Then science failed in a major way with structuralism.  Structuralism focused on the new sciences of linguistics, anthropology, and sociology, which had the potential to more directly answer what thinking consists of (linguistics) what humanity is (anthropology) and how we live (sociology). The structuralists examining each of these fields, plus many more (history, corporate structure, art interpretation, etc.) found the same underlying structure within each field.  This was taken to be a truth about our universe, that there is a common structure to -- basically everything.  This was a dominant view in continental thinking for decades.  THEN critics of structuralists, most notably Foucault and Derrida, showed how the methods of structural analysis presupposed the very structure that was supposedly later "discovered" in these sciences!  Science was not immune to skewed sociological assumptions determining its conclusions.
Post-modernism, which focusses a jaundiced and suspicious eye on the possibly self-serving nature of the assumptions behind even the most "objective" of rationales, was originally called post-structuralism.
Rationality is not rational
Kant in his Critique of Pure Reason, severely limited the role of rationality in developing a worldview.  However, he left in a few caveats -- that there are some rational aspects of our world that are so clearly true that they can be known non-empirically.  His go-to example was Euclidean Geometry.  But within 40 years, multiple no-Euclidean geometries were discovered, and 80 years after that, our universe has been demonstrated to be non-Euclidean.  Kant's remaining diminished role for rationality -- was dramatically undermined.
Godel then showed that there can be true statements in a logic or math system which cannot be shown to be true within that system. And the Munchausen Trilemma shows that no reasoned conclusion can be justified without recourse to a fallacy.   Finally, logicians concluded that there are infinite different logics, hence "reasoning" will always involve a contingent choice between logic options, which cannot itself be justified logically.  https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think/article/abs/guide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians/EDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B12D877
What had the breakup of the enlightenment philosophic consensus lead to?
As you seem to have noticed the loss of that unifying enlightenment paradigm has led to some people abandoning rationality, or abandoning empiricism, or abandoning morality.
Your social justice warriors tend to be strongly influenced by post-modernism, and its suspicion that rationality is cover for rationalizations, and even science is easily skewed in ways that can often take decades of careful analysis to uncover.  Does this make them LESS thoughtful, and are they "dumbing down"?  I would argue NO!  The legitimate lesson of structuralism IS to be suspicious!
SJW tend to focus on a non-rational moral sense, and the realization that the mistreatment of minorities and the poor is immoral.  And that the rationales for cheering on police abuse of "criminals", and mistreatment of sexual and racial minorities, are generally just rationalizations for a hidden motive of bigotry and cruelty.  SJW seek to EMPOWER ethical thinking, not create a "circus".
Abandoning reasoning and empiricism entirely, and failure to engage in self-evaluative critique, however, will be fatal to any movement.  Post-modernists have taken too strong a lesson from Structuralism.
Despite the breakdown of the Enlightenment philosophic consensus, Steven Pinker studied the history of human mistreatment of each other, and found that there has been a long term steady trend toward humans being less and less violent toward each other.  He documented this in an excellent book titled The Better Angels of Our Nature.  The rate of human on human violence in contemporary western society has hit a hitherto amazingly low level.  We are becoming FAR MORE moral, not less.  Meanwhile, the Greek philosophers were far better at starting the process of reasoning than they were at moral theory.  They approved of slavery, caste systems, treating women as property, pedophilia, and opposed democracy. Don't treat the Greek founders of philosophy as a moral paragon.
As I note here in an answer on the Munchausen Trilemma, pragmatism provides a much more useful framework for accepting that science is fallible, and logical is useful but not itself "logical", and ethics should be taken seriously even if we can't "derive" it.   AND ethics should be evaluated both rationally and empirically, even if rationalism or empiricism themselves may have suspect justifications.   https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/64930/29339  Pragmatism accepts that our philosophic tools may be flawed, but they are useful tools none the less.

It seems that you might be saying that our moral sense is deteriorating along with our intelligence. Average IQ increases with time as people become more able to deal with abstractions. In Steven Pinker's view we have become less violent and more compassionate with time. See Pinker's work on evolutionary psychology. In my view, this is evidenced in the historical record. If it helps you personally, when I was your age in the 1970s there was a prevalent view that we were going to hell in a handcart. In my old age, I am more sanguine.
